# SQL: Repeated records by grouping some columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a data like,

```
ID  Name    ItemA   ItemB   ItemC
OXZ234  Adam    4   4   5
OXZ234  Adam    1   2   3
OXZ345  Tarzen  6   7   8
OXDER2  William 9   8   2
OXDER2  William 0   8   0
```

I need to find how much of food each person eats. For example by referring first two records I can say, Adam of ID OXZ234 ate ItemA-5, ItemB-6 and ItemC-8. But for small amount of data this kind of manual calculation is affordable. I have a million data records like this. So initially I need to find the records which is having same ID and name but only items count differing.

I have tried the query to find duplicate records by grouping all columns like below,

```
select ID,Name,ItemA,ItemB,ItemC, COUNT(*)
from DATA_REFRESH
group by ID,Name,ItemA,ItemB,ItemC
having COUNT(*) > 1
```

But Now I have to identify records having items columns differed.

So the expected output is like,

```
OXZ234  Adam    2
OXDER2  William 2
OXZ345  Tarzen  1
```

Any suggestion would be helpful!

Comment: is this mysql or sql-server ?

Comment: you should probably spend time rewording your narrative as you have mislead others by saying you need to find how much food a person eats, then find duplicates, but ultimately you say you need to find a count of non duplicate (unique) records.  SQL-server has window functions that mysql doesn't have so please tag which system you are using NOT both!

Comment: also if trying to distinguish between duplicate and non duplicate you might consider enhancing your sample data with both cases in it and then your desired result to reflect this new data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simply try like this,

```
select ID,Name,COUNT(*)
from Sample_Check
group by ID,Name
having COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: how does a count give him a sum of food eaten?

Comment: I dont think he is trying to find the sum. as per the comment he made for previous answer he is trying to find number of records having same ID and name but differing item values.

Comment: Yes, TomFarCry, I have added the expected output in the question now.

Comment: @TomFarCry yeah I see that now reading a bit more OP is definitely misleading his needs by stating "I need to find how much of food each person eats. For example by referring first two records I can say, Adam of ID OXZ234 ate ItemA-5, ItemB-6 and ItemC-8".  But upon reading further this appears where OP is stuck: "But Now I have to identify records having items columns differed." so he found the duplicates but now it seems is wanting to find the count of non duplicates

Answer (score 4):

You want SUM

```
select ID,
       Name,
       sum(ItemA) as ItA, 
       sum(ItemB) as ItB,
       sum(ItemC) as ItC,
       count(ID) as Occurrences -- Counts the number of entries per person
from DATA_REFRESH
group by ID,Name
having count(ID) >1 -- restricts this so only those with more than one entry appear
```

Comment: It is summing okay. But i need a count that particular record is occuring `n` times in a table only differing in item count

Answer (score 1):

Hi,
 You can have a simple query without having clause,

```
  select ID,Name,COUNT(*)
from DATA_REFRESH
group by ID,Name order by COUNT(*) desc ;
```